# Shift plotting of arrow one bar left on MACD

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'd like to write a trend indicator for the MACD (plot highs and lows, then figure out when a high is higher/lower than the previous, etc.). Essentially doing something like pivot points, but on the MACD.

The code below should plot an arrow when a MACD value is higher than the current, and also higher than the bar before that. However the actual arrow appears (of course) on the current bar. I tried "shifting" the arrow one bar left, but can't figure out how that's done. Some sources use `bar_index`, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
//@version=5
indicator("MACD Trend")

// Setup and plot MACD
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
plot(macdLine, color=color.blue)

// Setup and plot arrows
high_cross = macdLine[1] > macdLine and macdLine[1] > macdLine[2]
plotshape(high_cross, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.top)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot*()` functions have a parameter called `offset`.

> ***offset (series int)*** Shifts shapes to the left or to the right on the given number of bars. Default is 0.

So, you can do:

```
plotshape(high_cross, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.top, offset=-1)
```

Comment: I didn't see that.  Thank you.